# Need to add a localStorage for my simple ToDoList

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I have a simple to do app that creates to dos and displays them to the screen. However, I wan't to save these to local storage so if someone leaves the page and returns, reloads the page, etc. the to do items remain. 
I need to finish it until tomorrow and i'm struggling since hours to implement a localStorage :(
I appreciate every help. Thanks in advance.

here is my code on js.fiddle.net :

```
if (event.target.classList.contains('js-delete-todo')) {
    const itemKey = event.target.parentElement.dataset.key;
    todoloeschen(itemKey);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mymyyy/haset7gc/

Comment: I will give you simple tip on top of the other answers. Always and always program in English language. There is nothing more frustrating in life than finding a source code that is written in mongoloid and you can't understand anything. Your fiddle would be more helpful if variable names etc would be in English.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the window.localStorage method

By setting data  to the localStorage 
`localStorage.setItem('key', value );`

And also getting 
`localStorage.getItem('key', value);`

You can also save an array by passing data

```
// let’s say am saving an array of books with objects values 
localStorage.setItem('books',JSON.stringify(books));

let books = localStorage.getItem('books');
books = JSON.parse(books);
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

To save an item to local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem(variable, 'value');
```

To get data from local storage:

```
let var = localStorage.getItem(variable);
```

Take a look at the documentation.  It is really simple.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage